# what does " that rule out the possibility of including something" means here?

Tags: meaning

I failed to get the concept of the bold following part:

> So if we are genetically disposed to develop synaesthesia, does ***that rule out the possibility of inducing the experience?***

Answer (score 1):

The word 'does' is part of the expression.

> *Does* that rule out the possibility of inducing the experience?

Synaesthesia is something that scientists are interested in, so of course they want to study it. It would be easy to study it if we could *induce* some people to experience it (perhaps by giving them a drug that gives them synaesthesia). Therefore, scientists would be very happy if there's a *possibility* of inducing it.

However, it seems that synaesthesia is genetic. If that's true, it could prevent or otherwise *rule out* the possibility of inducing synaesthesia. But we're not sure, it might *not* rule it out.

That's why the author is asking us the open question: **Does it rule out the possibility of inducing synaesthesia?**

Answer (score 1):

- **So if we are genetically disposed to develop synaesthesia, `∅`<sub>then</sub>
   does `that`<sub>ref=prior sentence</sub> `rule out`<sub>meaning=eliminate</sub> the possibility of inducing the experience?**

*rule out* is a phrasal verb meaning "eliminate".  *To rule out a possibility* means to figuratively "scratch it off" or "mark through it" to indicate it is no longer going to be considered as an option.

A potential answers could be:

- **Yes!**  That **rules out** any possibility, so don't waste your time trying if you don't have the genetics.
- **No!** Just because one is genetically *disposed* to develop synaesthesia on their own, that does **not rule** out the possibility that we might be able to induce the experience with drugs, flashing lights, etc.

Also:

- *The coach of the defeated football team went on TV and said, "If some people think they can **rule us out** because of this one game, their sorely mistaken. We made some technical errors, and we're going to fix them.  We've got a healthy team and we're still very much in the running."*